# Problem running Ubiquity when compiled from source

Tags: ubiquity, install-from-source

I've written a patch for Ubiquity that I'm try to test. I've modified the Ubiquity source and successfully run `./configure`, `make` and `sudo make install`, however I'm having problems running it. When I enter `ubiquity` into the terminal, I am prompted to install it from the repositories. I have searched the `/etc/ubiquity` directory, but all there is there is a log file generated during the installation.

How should I get Ubiquity running? The output of `sudo make install` is attached below.

```
Making install in desktop
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/desktop'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/desktop'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
test -z "/usr/local/share/applications" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/share/applications"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 oem-config-prepare-gtk.desktop oem-config-prepare-kde.desktop ubiquity-gtkui.desktop ubiquity-kdeui.desktop '/usr/local/share/applications'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/desktop'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/desktop'
Making install in pixmaps
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/pixmaps'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/pixmaps'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
test -z "/usr/local/share/ubiquity/pixmaps" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/share/ubiquity/pixmaps"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 world_map-960.png zoom-in.png '/usr/local/share/ubiquity/pixmaps'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/pixmaps'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/pixmaps'
Making install in po
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/po'
linguas="af am an ar ast az be bg bn br bs ca cs csb da de el eo es et eu fa fi fr fy ga gl gu he hi hr hu hy id is it ja ka kk ko ku lb lt lv mk ms nb ne nl nn no oc pl pt pt_BR ro ru sd sk sl sq sr sv ta tg th tl tr uk vi zh_CN zh_HK zh_TW "; \
    for lang in $linguas; do \
      dir=/usr/local/share/locale/$lang/LC_MESSAGES; \
      /bin/bash /home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/build/install-sh -d $dir; \
      if test -r $lang.gmo; then \
        /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 $lang.gmo $dir/ubiquity.mo; \
        echo "installing $lang.gmo as $dir/ubiquity.mo"; \
      else \
        /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./$lang.gmo $dir/ubiquity.mo; \
        echo "installing ./$lang.gmo as" \
         "$dir/ubiquity.mo"; \
      fi; \
      if test -r $lang.gmo.m; then \
        /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 $lang.gmo.m $dir/ubiquity.mo.m; \
        echo "installing $lang.gmo.m as $dir/ubiquity.mo.m"; \
      else \
        if test -r ./$lang.gmo.m ; then \
          /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./$lang.gmo.m \
        $dir/ubiquity.mo.m; \
          echo "installing ./$lang.gmo.m as" \
           "$dir/ubiquity.mo.m"; \
        else \
          true; \
        fi; \
      fi; \
    done
installing af.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/af/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing am.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/am/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing an.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/an/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing ar.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing ast.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/ast/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing az.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/az/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing be.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/be/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing bg.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing bn.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/bn/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing br.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/br/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing bs.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/bs/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing ca.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing cs.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing csb.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/csb/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing da.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing de.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing el.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/el/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing eo.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/eo/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing es.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing et.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/et/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing eu.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/eu/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing fa.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/fa/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing fi.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/fi/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing fr.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing fy.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/fy/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing ga.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/ga/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing gl.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/gl/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing gu.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/gu/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing he.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/he/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing hi.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/hi/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing hr.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/hr/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing hu.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/hu/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing hy.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/hy/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing id.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing is.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/is/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing it.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing ja.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing ka.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/ka/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing kk.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/kk/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing ko.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing ku.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/ku/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing lb.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/lb/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing lt.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/lt/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing lv.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/lv/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing mk.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/mk/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing ms.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/ms/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing nb.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/nb/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing ne.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/ne/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing nl.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing nn.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/nn/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing no.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/no/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing oc.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/oc/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing pl.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing pt.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/pt/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing pt_BR.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing ro.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/ro/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing ru.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing sd.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/sd/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing sk.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/sk/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing sl.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/sl/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing sq.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/sq/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing sr.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing sv.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing ta.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/ta/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing tg.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/tg/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing th.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/th/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing tl.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/tl/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing tr.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing uk.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing vi.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing zh_CN.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing zh_HK.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/zh_HK/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
installing zh_TW.gmo as /usr/local/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/ubiquity.mo
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/po'
Making install in ubiquity
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/ubiquity'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/ubiquity'
test -z "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ubiquity" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ubiquity"
 /bin/bash ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   _osextras.la '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ubiquity'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/_osextras.so /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ubiquity/_osextras.so
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/_osextras.lai /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ubiquity/_osextras.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/_osextras.a /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ubiquity/_osextras.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ubiquity/_osextras.a
libtool: install: ranlib /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ubiquity/_osextras.a
libtool: finish: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ubiquity
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ubiquity

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/ubiquity'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/ubiquity'
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/src'
Making install in panel
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/src/panel'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/src/panel'
test -z "/usr/local/lib/ubiquity" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/lib/ubiquity"
  /bin/bash ../../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c panel '/usr/local/lib/ubiquity'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c panel /usr/local/lib/ubiquity/panel
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/src/panel'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/src/panel'
Making install in cheese
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/src/cheese'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/src/cheese'
test -z "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ubiquity" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ubiquity"
 /bin/bash ../../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   cheese.la '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ubiquity'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/cheese.so /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ubiquity/cheese.so
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/cheese.lai /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ubiquity/cheese.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/cheese.a /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ubiquity/cheese.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ubiquity/cheese.a
libtool: install: ranlib /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ubiquity/cheese.a
libtool: finish: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ubiquity
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ubiquity

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
test -z "/usr/local/share/pygobject/2.0/defs" || /bin/mkdir -p "/usr/local/share/pygobject/2.0/defs"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 cheese.defs '/usr/local/share/pygobject/2.0/defs'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/src/cheese'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/src/cheese'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/src'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/src'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity/src'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/notgary/Projects/bzr-branches/ubiquity'
```

Comment: Did you check from the "make install" output that the binary was install into /usr/bin an not into other location ?

Comment: Yeah I've checked them all out. I've added the output of `make install` if you want to check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, I would not recommend installing an Ubuntu package using make/make install.

The general advice would be to do the following:

```
apt-get source ubiquity
cd ubiquity-*
debuild # this will take a long time
sudo dpkg -i ../ubiquity*.deb ../ubiquity-ubuntu-artwork*.deb ../ubiquity-frontend-gtk*.deb
```

See the wiki for more (too much) information about building packages: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete#Building%20the%20Package%20Locally%20%28Binary%20Only%29

Answer (score 0):

You are installing ubiquity into the wrong place, it is expected to be installed into /usr, many source configure scripts use /usr/local to prevent you from installing over an existing packaged version.
You should be able to run ubiquity with:

```
/usr/local/bin/ubiquity
```

Still there are some applications which require to be installed into /usr, if that is the case then you must build ubiquity with

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
```

Comment: I've rebuilt Ubiquity using `./configure --prefix=/usr` (I ran `make uninstall` and `make distclean` beforehand), but when I try to run `/usr/local/bin/ubiquity` I get the error message `bash: /usr/local/bin/ubiquity: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Chris Configured with `--prefix=/usr` it should be in `/usr/bin/`

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same error message when trying to execute `/usr/bin/ubiquity`