# How to build and compile a bzr branch for testing

Tags: apt, development, patch, bazaar, install-from-source

When I pull down a bzr branch using

```
bzr branch lp:ubuntu/<package name>
```

I get one set of source files. However, when i go

```
apt-get source <package name>
```

I get another. The command

```
debuild
```

will not work on the first, but it will on the second, and this is the recommended way of building packages from source on Ubuntu, and I think Debian as well (see this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22500/problem-running-ubiquity-when-compiled-from-source)).

If I want to submit a patch to Ubuntu, the easiest way is us bzr to `branch` the code and then `push` it back out once I'm done, something that obviously won't work with the `apt-get source` method since the list of downloaded files are different.

How am I supposed to pull source code down, test a patch, then push it back out? Right now, it seems like I have to test the changes using the `apt-get source` method before pulling down a branch with `bar branch` and completely redoing the changes there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to build from a bazaar branch, the command you are looking for is `bzr builddeb` or `bzr builddeb -S` for a source package. This is part of the [bzr-builddeb](http://packages.ubuntu.com/bzr-builddeb) [image: Install bzr-builddeb] package.

For further information you should check out the [Ubuntu Distributed Development documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DistributedDevelopment/Documentation) and bzr-builddeb's documentation located at:

```
/usr/share/doc/bzr-builddeb/user_manual/index.html
```

Specifically:

```
/usr/share/doc/bzr-builddeb/user_manual/building.html
```

The bazaar branch and the package in the archive retrieved with `apt-get source` should have the same contents. The only reason that I can think of as to why they might differ is if the package importer is failing for the specific package you are interested in. There is a [site tracking](http://package-import.ubuntu.com/status/) which packages are failing to import.